# Where to find ERNI REL14-A2 1.3 equivalent?

Tags: relay

I have problem to find equivalent of these relays.
During my research I found that "ERNI" has stoped to manufacturer these relays.
I can't find datasheet of the relay and can't find any specifications too.

Here is visual specifications:
ERNI REL14-A2 1.3

Driving side of the relay : 12VDC

Power side of the relay 250VAC 4A

If anyone have some information about equivalent please shere.

Here is some pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: [Did you ask Bert?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bert_and_Ernie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding an exact FIT may be difficult, maybe impossible,but matching FORM (SPDT) and FUNCTION 12Vdc coil , contacts >=4A, 240Vac is easy.

IF FORM FIT and FUNCTION cannot be found, with modifications, it is possible.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5LA-14-CF-DC12/Z2576-ND/1210594